# How to remove selected items from JList

Tags: java, jlist

I am trying to remove selected items from a JList when the user clicks a button.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
private void clickActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   myList.remove(myList.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

When I click the button to remove the items, I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 3
```

How do I fix this error, and does my code even remove multiple items?

Comment: To what class does `clickActionPerformed` belong to? You need to add an `ActionListener` to your button and then override `actionPerformed`. Are you sure that you get the index-out-of-bounds exception at the place you show us us?

Answer (score 5):

You can delete multiple items from your DefaultListModel if you start deleting from the highest selected index to the lowest. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    switch(e.getActionCommand()){
    case "Remove": {
        int index = this.list[0].getSelectedIndices().length - 1;

        while (this.list[0].getSelectedIndices().length != 0) {
            this.defaultListModel[0].removeElementAt(this.list[0].getSelectedIndices()[index--]);
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing objects rather than indices:

```
private JList<MyObject> list;
private DefaultListModel<MyObject> myobjectListModel;
public FabricaCoches() 
{
....
myobjectListModel = new DefaultListModel<MyObject>();
list = new JList<MyObject>(myobjectListModel);
....
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    // get a list with selected objects
    List<MyObject> selectedItems = list.getSelectedValuesList();

     for (MyObject o: selectedItems)
        myobjectListModel.removeElement(o);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[] oo=new Object[] { "Clark", "Skill" };
        for(Object o :oo)
            model.addElement(o);
        final JList list = new JList(model);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(list.getSelectedIndex()>=0)
                model.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using some kind of a ListModel to construct the JList? If thats the case you can just do the following:

```
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
list.add("foo");
```

then you just need to do this when your "Blacklist-Button" was clicked:

```
list.remove(JList.getSelectedIndex());
```